# How to make a configurable json file for CRA bundle

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I use CRA to bundle my react app.

There is a requirement for the bundle to have a static configurable json, for example

```
//config.json
{
  "url": "url",
  "otherConfig": "otherConfig"
}
```

The app should read the url from here and use it.
And in case there is a need to change it or any other config they can just edit that json. So that there is no build/deployment step.

Is this possible to achieve?
Or what are the possible issues?

Did any of you get to do something like this?

Comment: Since there is no build step you can't "bundle" it. You could load the file using `fetch` when your `App` did mount and provide the value as a global (for simplicity) or via context (to avoid collision and such). Also you need to be more specific about "read the url from here and use it" use how?

Comment: if you put the file on the public folder and use fetch to GET /config.json, it should do the trick. but if you need to change it, you would need to ssh/ftp into the machine to update it maybe using env variables and restarting the server?

Comment: @ErichMenezes the updating part of json is not under my jurisdiction, what I care about is my app reads it. Using a fetch in public folder seems to be a good idea. However is it not async? is it possible my app code will start running during that fetch?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko fetch('from where?')

Comment: @YuryTarabanko read the `url` and use it for api requests.

Comment: "they can just edit that json" so I suppose you already have a file on server.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it's going to be put right into the build folder.

Comment: Then it would be relative to index.html `fetch('/config.json')`

Comment: yes but you suggest to use it after my `App` did mount, will it just work with that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy with a js file.

Make a `config.js` file

```
window.config = {
  "config": "xxx"
}
```

Then import it in `index.js`

```
import './config.js'
```

open `public/index.html` and add the following script

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
```

After building, copy-paste `config.js` into the `build` folder.